# How to enable Mass payment in paypal for shopify MarketPlace App

Tags: paypal, shopify

I am trying to connect the BOLD MarketPlace app to the PayPal. I have changed the PayPal with the new account and also given permission to the BOLD MarketPlace app.

But when I go to pay for the user then it showing me an error message that **"We're sorry, but your PayPal account isn't currently eligible to send mass payments. Please contact either PayPal Customer service or your account manager"**.

Answer (score 0):

MassPay is not enabled for all PayPal accounts by default. I think you need to contact their customer service to apply for it.